# Using git commit hash with maven-release-plugin

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to set the release version number of our app to something like `1.5.0.057b2009` with the abbreviated git commit hash in it.

## Setup

I'm trying to use `maven-release-plugin` in combination with `git-commit-id-plugin`.

Our base version number in development is 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <tagNameFormat>APP-NAME-@{version}</tagNameFormat>
        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
        <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
        <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
        <pushChanges>true</pushChanges>
        <branchName>${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.x</branchName>
        <releaseVersion>${project.version}.${git.commit.id.abbrev}</releaseVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
        <generateGitPropertiesFile>false</generateGitPropertiesFile><!-- somehow necessary. otherwise the variables are not available in the pom -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

## Build

The whole project is built with the following command:

```
mvn -B release:prepare
```

## Problem

The maven release plugin completely ignores the `releaseVersion` property. The actual release version would be `1.5.0`, how can I handle this?

Comment: How do you run the release build?

Comment: I build the project with `mvn -B release:prepare`. I updated my question.

Comment: try to use -X and see if the value is used

Comment: According to the debug output, the git commit hash is not evaluated: `[DEBUG]   (f) releaseVersion = 1.9.0-SNAPSHOT.${git.commit.id.abbrev}`

Comment: try to add `pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.1.7:revision` to the `preparationGoals`

Comment: Now the git plugin successfully parses the git hash (according to its log). But it's ignored by maven-release-plugin. It does not even remove the -SNAPSHOT.

Comment: The generated pom.xml looks loke this: `<parent>
    <artifactId>App-Name</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
    <version>1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.${git.commit.id.abbrev}</version>
</parent>`